# On CentOS 7 allow certain users Read & Write to mounted file systems of different types

Tags: permissions, filesystems, ntfs, cifs, xfs

I have a query around mounting file systems of differing types in such a way that a selection of users have r/w access to them.

Here's the scenario. I've rebuilt a media server to Centos 7 minimal and installed Plex and assorted other media tools on it successfully. Because it's using existing media libraries it's essential to retain the existing file systems and so I'm left with a variety of data locations which are as follows

- A local 1.5TB xfs partition (flushed clean at build time)
- A local 3TB NTFS partition (retained from previous Windows build)
- 2 x CIFS shares on WD Mycloud devices (I struggled to connect via NFS so just stuck with CIFS)

I've mounted all of the above under `/mnt/media1-4` and can read everything happily as any user, but I need to give two users WRITE access to all sources. I've created a group and added the two users to the group.

So far the only mount point which I have carte blanche access to is the NTFS partition as this is mounted with the following in `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/sdc2 /mnt/media2     ntfs     rw,user,exec,umask=000  0 0
```

If I understand correctly this presents the storage and masks all permissions as 777, yes?

I understand `umask=000` isn't valid for xfs and cifs file systems though. On the xfs file system I've set permissions on all folders as 775 and applied `chgrp <mygroup> * -R` to the content but I still can't write to it with any account other than root.

Is there a way to mount xfs and cifs with a mask similar to the ntfs mount that will not require me to go and rewrite permissions on all of my valuable data?

Comment: You can specific the uid, gid and mode when mounting the file system as type xfs or cifs. Run "man mount" for more information